# Logic Pro: can't see the loop checkbox in track info

Tags: logic-pro

please see attachment. Can't see the loop checkbox under the 'mute' one: how to?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just found out: cycle mode was active. When active, no loop checkbox.

[image]